# How can i insert into a table that has many relational with other table

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I using knex with objection js and i want to insert to roomType table with roomImage table at the same because table roomType has many roomImage
This my database

```js
.createTable(tableName.roomImage, (table) => {
        table.increments('id').notNullable()
        table.string('imageUrl').notNullable()
    }).createTable(tableName.roomType, (table) => {
        table.increments('id').notNullable()
        table.string('type').notNullable()
        table.string('description').notNullable()
        table.float('price').notNullable()
        table.integer('bed').notNullable()
        table.integer('image_id').references('id').inTable(tableName.roomImage)
    })
```

This is my model

```js
const { Model } = require('objection')
const tableNames = require('../../constants/tablename')

class Image extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return tableNames.roomImage
    }
    static get idColumn() {
        return 'id'
    }
}

class RoomType extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return tableNames.roomType
    }
    static get idColumn() {
        return 'id'
    }
    static get relationalMapping() {
        return {
            imageUrl: {
                relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
                modelClass: Image,
                join: {
                    from: "roomType.image_id",
                    to: 'roomImage.id'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = RoomType
```

This is my code

```js
router.post('/create', async (req, res, next) => {

    const { type, price, bed, description, roomImage } = req.body
    try {
        await schema.validate(req.body, {
            abortEarly: false
        })
        const existRoomType = await RoomType.query().findOne({ type }).first()
        if (existRoomType) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'This role already exist' })
        } else {
            const tx = await RoomType.transaction(async trx => {
                const data = await RoomType.query(trx).insertGraph({
                    type, price, bed, description, roomImage
                }, { relate: true })
                res.json({ data })
            })
            console.log(roomImage);
            res.json({ data })
        }
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
})
```

This is the json body that i want to insert, I want to insert many image into roomtype table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZnvu.png)

Comment: what is the problem you are facing, and what sql server you are using ?

Comment: if the room type has many images then the foreign key should be in the roomImage table and not the roomType table